# Infinispan file-store creates binary folders with multiple .dat files

Tags: apache-camel, infinispan

I am using the below infinispan configuration file and running into a weird issue. On startup the application creates multiple folders (one for each digit of the byte array 0 to 255) and each folder contains .dat file (in my case idempotent.dat). Also the content of the file are FCS1 for all the files created.

What I was expecting is that it will create a single file (**/ap/efts/data/stage/cache/idempotent.dat**) which has all the cached objects. 
Can someone please identify what is causing this issue? I am using a camel-infinispan component to create Infinispan based idempotent repository.

**NOTE:** This was working correctly in infinispan version 7.0. For reference, I am also providing infinispan 7.0 configuration file as well as the spring bean configuration for idempotent repository.

[image]

**infinispan.xml (10.0)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:10.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-10.0.xsd" 
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:10.0">

    <cache-container default-cache="idempotent">
        <local-cache name="idempotent">
            <expiration lifespan="1800000" max-idle="1800000" interval="60000" />
            <persistence passivation="true">
                <file-store path="/ap/efts/data/stage/cache" purge="true">
                    <write-behind thread-pool-size="5" />
                </file-store>
            </persistence>
            <memory>
                <binary eviction="MEMORY" size="1000000" />
            </memory>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

**infinispan.xml (7.0)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.0">

    <cache-container default-cache="default">
        <local-cache name="idempotent">
            <eviction max-entries="10000" strategy="LIRS"/>
            <persistence passivation="false">
                <file-store path="/ap/efts/data/stage/cache" max-entries="10000" purge="false">
                </file-store>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

**spring bean configuration**

```
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="infinispan.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="infinispanRepo" class="org.apache.camel.component.infinispan.processor.idempotent.InfinispanIdempotentRepository"
        factory-method="infinispanIdempotentRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="cacheManager" />
        <constructor-arg value="idempotent" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is creating a file for each segment (caches internally are organized in segments). The default is 256. This makes operations such as iteration much faster.
You can disable segmentation at the store level by adding a `segmented="false"` attribute to the `file-store` element

Comment: Thank you @Tristan. I have to use infinispan 10.0.1 as it is the most updated version available in camel-infinispan dependency. segmented attribute is not available for file-store in that version. However I see that it is present in 10.1 version. Is there another way in infinispan 10.0.1 in which I can turn off segmentation? Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can upgrade to Infinispan 10.1: the Camel connector will work correctly.